# 2D renderer blocking particle system color changing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering, particle-system

I have created a particle system that appear after an enemy died.
It changes color to the color on the sprite renderer of the enemy.
Before I set the Universal RP 2D renderer, as the graphic renderer of my project, it worked.
But now it is always changing the particle system color to purple.
I tried to toggle it off and it worked again.
So what can I do if I want to use 2D shader graphs and the particle system color changing.

```
        ParticleSystem.MainModule setting = (My particle system).main;
        setting.startColor = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().color;
```

Those are the lines I used to change the color.